# Angular replaced @angular/http with @angular/common/http

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am in the process of upgrading my project and need to change my api from `@angular/http` to `@angular/common/http`. I main question do I just need to change the import or will the code need to change?

Old Version Code
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams, Headers } from "@angular/http";

```
getGridPage(gridQueryData: OrderTemplateTool.Core.Models.Grid.GridQueryData): Promise<Response> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrls.GetGridPage, JSON.stringify(gridQueryData), { headers: ServiceBase.headers }).toPromise();
}
```

New import for package has been deprecated

```
import { HttpClient, Response, URLSearchParams, Headers } from "@angular/common/http";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently went through this and found the code I was using worked fine once I updated the import.  HttpClient, Response, URLSearchParams, Headers should work the same with the new import.